# Correct work querySelectorAll with forEach into another forEach

Tags: javascript

I have some product list on my page
I need to run all products and get id (article) and name of product
ID need get from data-id into ".eshop_js-add-to-cart"
Name need to get from ".eshop-item-v2-title"

Needed after click on CartButton take data-id from clicked button, not the first and take his name

```js
var CartButton = document.querySelectorAll(".eshop_js-add-to-cart");

CartButton.forEach((item) => {
  item.onclick = function () {
    console.log("addToCart works");

    var NameProductList = document.querySelector(".eshop-item-v2-title").textContent;
    var ProductIdList = document.querySelector('.eshop_js-add-to-cart');
    var ProductIdCountList = ProductIdList.getAttribute('data-id');

    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
      event: 'addToCart',
      ecommerce: {
        add: {
          actionField: { list: 'category' },
          products: [{
            name: NameProductList,
            id: ProductIdCountList,

          }]
        }
      }
    });
    console.log("dataLayer works");
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="eshop-item-v2-wrap" data-product-id="507">
  <div class="product-card_interact-cont">
    <div class="eshop-item-v2-buttons">
      <div class="eshop_js-add-to-cart eshop_add-to-cart-btn" data-id="507">
        <span class="eshop-item-v2-btn-label">Add to cart</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="eshop-item-v2-title">Product 1</span>
</div>


<div class="eshop-item-v2-wrap" data-product-id="3347">
  <div class="product-card_interact-cont">
    <div class="eshop-item-v2-buttons">
      <div class="eshop_js-add-to-cart eshop_add-to-cart-btn pressed js-done" data-id="3347">
        <span class="eshop-item-v2-btn-label">Add to cart</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="eshop-item-v2-title">Product 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` always selects the first matching element inside the document. You need to limit the scope here, by calling this method on an actual element inside your structure, that makes sense. You need to go up to the `.eshop-item-v2-wrap` element first (`parentNode` is the property that holds an element's parent node, in plain JS DOM), and then call `querySelector` on that, to have it find only the `.eshop-item-v2-title` element inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats wng with the code?

Your selector quesries `document.querySelector(".eshop-item-v2-title")` and `document.querySelector('.eshop_js-add-to-cart')` will always return the first node having class `eshop-item-v2-title` and `eshop_js-add-to-cart` regardles of the button that you clicked.

**Solution.**

You can identify which button you clicked by using `e.currentTarget` insuide the clicke event listner. You can select the closest element with class `eshop-item-v2-wrap` which can be called as the container div with `e.currentTarget.closest(".eshop-item-v2-wrap")`. Your reired nodes can be targetted now by using this node. Simply by using `parentNode.querySelector(".eshop-item-v2-title")` and `parentNode.querySelector('.eshop_js-add-to-cart')` where `parentNode` is the result of selector `e.currentTarget.closest(".eshop-item-v2-wrap")`

```js
var CartButton = document.querySelectorAll(".eshop_js-add-to-cart");

CartButton.forEach((item) => {
  item.onclick = function (e) {
    console.log("addToCart works", e.currentTarget);
    const parentNode = e.currentTarget.closest(".eshop-item-v2-wrap");

    var NameProductList = parentNode.querySelector(".eshop-item-v2-title").textContent;
    var ProductIdList = parentNode.querySelector('.eshop_js-add-to-cart');
    var ProductIdCountList = ProductIdList.getAttribute('data-id');
    
    console.log('NameProductList', NameProductList);
    console.log('ProductIdList', NameProductList);
    console.log('ProductIdCountList', NameProductList);

    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
      event: 'addToCart',
      ecommerce: {
        add: {
          actionField: { list: 'category' },
          products: [{
            name: NameProductList,
            id: ProductIdCountList,
          }]
        }
      }
    });
    console.log("dataLayer works");

  };
});
```

```html
<div class="eshop-item-v2-wrap" data-product-id="507">
  <div class="product-card_interact-cont">
    <div class="eshop-item-v2-buttons">
      <div class="eshop_js-add-to-cart eshop_add-to-cart-btn" data-id="507">
        <span class="eshop-item-v2-btn-label">Add to cart</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="eshop-item-v2-title">Product 1</span>
</div>


<div class="eshop-item-v2-wrap" data-product-id="3347">
  <div class="product-card_interact-cont">
    <div class="eshop-item-v2-buttons">
      <div class="eshop_js-add-to-cart eshop_add-to-cart-btn pressed js-done" data-id="3347">
        <span class="eshop-item-v2-btn-label">Add to cart</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="eshop-item-v2-title">Product 2</span>
</div>
```